# ASP.NET: Dynamic multi submit button with fast post back

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I have a webpage for selling theater ticket. i have a question with theater saloon plan.

For example the main saloon has 500 chairs that i created them with dynamic button (first read from database the count of chairs and the space between them and create button with specific size and color ) and all of the buttons in one update panel but when user clicked on chairs and the loader display but this way for reserve is not fast and the user do not like to waste her-his time for reserving for example more than 5 chairs. my question is : How can i define the button for user when they click on each chairs to reserve them with very fast postback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The submitting of ajax call is slower because you have 500 button in update panel and you have to send the state of all those when state of on button is changed. You can send single call when user has made all selection for reservations. You can `checkbox` with each seat, might be [CheckBoxList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.checkboxlist.aspx) and show only non-reserved seats. If you like to have buttons you can use toggle buttons to select and deselect seat and you have to submit the reservation with other button that should be click once to confirm resrvations.

**Edit** Based on comments.

If you want to reserve seat on selection of `button` / `checkbox` and you want it to be faster than update panel wont be the base choice which wraps all the button you have for seats you can use [jQuery ajax with asp.net](http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/) as it could only send the data of single `button` / `checkbox` that is changed.

Comment: thank you  :) , but on each button click i should check that chair does not reserved by another user, and save the chairs on data base

Comment: If you want that then you can use jQuery ajax instead of postback.

Comment: yes ,  i should use jQuery Ajax, thank you. :)  . because on each chairs i have a post back , so this way i guest better .

Answer (score 0):

Actually you are following wrong methodology here. You should avoid Postback  when single seat selected. Instead You may use single postback for N-number of seat selection.

You can use hidden variable or Check box list or many other way is there in asp.net to identify the selected seats. Use any one of them and use single postback per order. that will increase your application performance.

Comment: thank you :) , but on each chair reserved i should check that chair does not reserved by another person , and reserved it on database that avoid to reserved one chair with multi user